# H1 background-color property fills the whole line

Tags: html, css

I currently have a `text-align: center;` h1 element. It also has a `background-color: #000506;`. The current issue is that this background color fills the whole line as shown here:
[image: filling the whole line]
What I want it to do is to only fill the area where the text is. The only way I've been able to do this is making the left and right margins really large, and even then it's not perfect.

```css
margin-left: 600px;
margin-right: 600px;
```

[image]

Comment: Put a `span` inside your `h1` and apply the background color to it

Comment: `h1` and related elements are block level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can reset display to use the table-layout model so it will shrink to fit content.

example

```css
h1 {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  
  /* extra style */
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  line-height:1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sheet List</h1>
```

---

theoraticly and very soon, display won't be needed, width and margin:auto will do fine when [`max-content`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_width_max-content) will be widely implemented.

```css
h1 {
  width:max-content;
  margin: auto;
  
  /* extra style */
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  line-height:1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sheet List</h1>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#fill
>
> **max-content**
>
> The intrinsic preferred width.

Comment: Can you explain the behavior ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak when using the table-layout model, the container shrinks or expand to adapt its size to the content. This the default display of HTML table. Inline-table does the same.

Comment: Oh i see, I haven't done much with tables I've always tried to avoid them as they can get pretty messy quickly, That is good to know tho, might wanna add it to the answe.

Comment: @ZohirSalak yep , html table is a real tag soup if content do not require them. the display properties gives a whole lot of option nowdays, even float becomes not that usefull anymore.

Comment: What i don't understand is Why when you use inline-block instead, margin auto doesn't take effect while with table it does.

Comment: @ZohirSalak because inline-block is a not a block level element, `text-align:center` on the parent will do in that case

Comment: So display table is block level and it can shrink or expand to fit, that's what makes it useful in this case

Comment: @ZohirSalak yes, but this is for a matter of cross browser implementation, soon , the way will be to use : width:max-content. , i'll add a snippet about this .